# What mechanism is used to allow one to call methods defined in ruby root scope from that scope?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, class-design, language-design

In ruby, when one defines a method in the root scope, it can be called from that scope:

```
def foo
  "foo"
end
foo #=> "foo"
```

In any other context this is not the case:

```
class Bar
  def foo
    "foo"
  end
  foo #=> Error: No Method `foo` for class Bar
end
```

What mechanism is used in setting up the `main` object (an instance of `Object`) that allows this to happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is really special cased in Ruby. If you define methods in the global scope they get actually defined on `Kernel` which is included in every object by default.

Kernel is also there when no other context is defined. Since Class inherits also from Kernel methods defined on it are also in scope in class scopes.

Comment: I didn't know that before - I'll think twice before writing such a method again!

Answer (score 1):

Just to confirm what Jakub Hampl said:

```
def foo
  "Debugging: self is #{self.inspect}"
end
foo # => "Debugging: self is main"

class Bar
  def goo
    foo
  end
end

Bar.new.goo # => "Debugging: self is #<Bar:0x1513cc0>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define it as a class method (`self`) instead of instance method

```
class Bar
  def self.foo
    "foo"
  end
  foo 
  #=> "foo"
end
```